# How do I assign a newly created object to a model it belongs to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

So suppose I have two Models -- Project and Task

I want user to be able to select an existing project and assign a task to it.

This needs to be done in a task_form, in other words, I use Task Controller.
I know if it's a project form, I can simply create a nested form using 
accepts_nested_attributes_for in my Project model. However, the problem is
I need to refer back to a higher level model.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a view for the task form where there is a drop down box of all existing projects.  You can use [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) to create the multiselect and then just have it put the id of the project in the project_id column.